# AsyncTask: onCancelled(Result) not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm cancelling an `AsyncTask` when the parent activity is paused (onPaused). What I'm observing is that the task is terminated, but the parameterized version of `onCancelled` is never called. However, if I replace it with the parameterless [`onCancelled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28%29) method, it always gets called as expected.

My code:

```
    //In the activity
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();

       System.out.println("ON PAUSE!");

       if(lastTask != null){
           lastTask.cancel(true);
       }
    }


    //In asynctask implementation

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        for(int i = 0;!isCancelled();i++){
            System.out.printf(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> Doing some work. Iteration %d%n", i);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Result result){
        System.out.println("ON CANCELLED (args)!");
    }
```

I'm testing in android 2.2 AVD.

---

UPDATE
According to the docs, this method was added in API level 11. I'm testing in an API lv8 virtual device, but compiling for lv16. So this method doesn't exist in the device OS. I'd probably expect an exception being thown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCancelled(Result result)` was introduced in API Level 11, i.e. Android 3.0.

Comment: I just updated my question with this info, but this was posted before, so solved. BTW, why it doesn't throw an exception when calling a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: I suppose you compiled with a high enough Project Build Target and/or specified a high enough minSdkVersion in the manifest file. Still, it seems kind of strange to me too.

Answer (score 3):

**protected void onCancelled ()** was introduced on API level 3.

Where as, **protected void onCancelled (Result result)** was introduced on API level 11 ie Android 3.0.